# Как настроить constraints программно?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, iphone

Привет!

Имеется экран с segmented control, который имеет 2 состояния. На картинке все видно:

[image]

Включен Autolayout. Так вот, как прописать constraints для верхней границы UITableView (отмечен желтым цветом) чтобы для первого состояния, таблица привязывалась к navigation bar, а во втором состоянии - к UIView(вьюшка с элементами Откуда-Куда).

Пробовал для каждого состояния вручную прописать tableView.frame = CGRectMake... , но такое не работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот тут есть хороший пример: [Creating UIViews programmatically with Auto Layout](http://matthewmorey.com/creating-uiviews-programmatically-with-auto-layout/)

> Since Xcode 4.0 I have exclusively developed views in my iOS apps with Interface Builder (IB). First with xibs and recently with Storyboards. I'm a fan of IB and have successfully released several apps that use Auto Layout in the often criticized Xcode 4.x version of IB. I have been able to avoid the most common IB compliant, merge issues, with good team communication and a bit of luck.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но не получается:( Посмотрите пожалуйста внизу, дополнение к посту.

Answer (score 0):

Попробовал следующее: при загрузке вьюшки в зависимости от состояния создаю constraints:

```
- (void)setCityConstraints {
    NSLog(@"set city constraints");
    tView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    NSLayoutConstraint *myConstraint =[NSLayoutConstraint
                                       constraintWithItem:self.tView
                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                       relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                       toItem:navBar
                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                       multiplier:1.0
                                       constant:0.0];

    [self.view addConstraint:myConstraint];
}

- (void)setInterCityConstraints {
    NSLog(@"set intercity constraints");
    tView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    NSLayoutConstraint *myConstraint =[NSLayoutConstraint
                                       constraintWithItem:self.tView
                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                       relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                       toItem:navBar
                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                       multiplier:1.0
                                       constant:50.0];

    [self.view addConstraint:myConstraint];
}
```

При первой загрузке все хорошо работает, но если я начну изменять состояния вьюшки, изменяя segmentedControl - то на второй форме tableView налезает на UIView (там где кнопки Откуда и Куда).

```
- (IBAction)orderTypeChanged:(id)sender {
    if (orderTypeControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        [self showCity];
        [self setCityConstraints];
    } else {
        [self showIntercity];
        [self setInterCityConstraints];
    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте добавить consraints не к navbar, а к topLayoutGuide, то есть

[NSLayoutConstraint
            constraintWithItem:self.view
            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
            relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
            toItem:self.topLayoutGuide
            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop // может и bottom, не уверен, нужно поиграться с этой штукой
            multiplier:1.0
            constant:50.0];

Comment: У вас нет возможности сделать это в xib? На своем опыте, обычно это решение

Comment: еще опишите пожалуйста, не выводятся ли в логи сообщения о неверных constraints?

Comment: Логи выводятся, что как раз эти констрейны неправильные и будут брейкнуты. Поэтому пришлось сделать костыли: вывожу инфу на 2 UITableView: своя таблица для каждого состояния